# Why i can not get the private key of certificate on keychain iOS when device have passcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, passcode

With Device have no passcode, i can extract private key in SecKeyRef , after that
i convert it to NSData. I get private key, it saved in encrypted form ASN.1. 

And then, when i set the passcode on my device, I can not extract private key. Why?